# copy specific files from s3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have some files in s3 bucket.

```
aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/

file-111-100x100.jpg
file-112-1400x1400.jpg
file-123-250x250.jpg
file-231-1400x1400.jpg
file-222-700x700.jpg
file-333-100x100.jpg
file-131-1400x1400.jpg
file-321-250x250.jpg
file-232-480x480.jpg
file-113-1400x1400.jpg
file-331-100x100.jpg
```

How to copy only files through aws command line which have 1400*1400 text like

```
file-112-1400x1400.jpg
file-231-1400x1400.jpg
file-131-1400x1400.jpg
file-113-1400x1400.jpg
```

Help me to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if awscli has a built-in way to do this, but I've always just used simple bash to do things like this. For example:

`for i in $(aws s3 ls s3://bucketname/ | grep 1400x1400); do aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/$i; done`

It's not the prettiest way to do it, but it's pretty general and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way would be using the aws cli `--include` and `--exclude` filters:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/ [dest] --exclude "*" --include "*1400x1400*"
```

where `[dest]` is your destination (i.e. an s3 path or local path)

Two points:

- If you only want to include certain files, you need to first `--exclude "*"` before including whatever pattern you specify. Also, the order of the filters matters.
- You can also apply this filter recursively using the `--recursive` flag

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters
More info on `aws s3 cp`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html